# Does VTK support SVG rendering?

Tags: dictionary, svg, vtk

I'm basically trying to do visualization on geographic maps using VTK, and would like to know if there is any possibility of working with vector images like .svg or .ai?
if not, what's your suggestion of making scalable maps using VTK?

Thanks.
Eb